# Integrating Paypal Payment and Invoicing APIs

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have been manually issuing invoices to charge my clients for services using Paypal.

Now I am creating an interface to allow them to purchase the services automatically on my website.

I also want to show them a history of their purchases. However, I cannot show a history of paid invoices using the Transaction Search API; I need to use the Invoicing > Search Invoices API.

I have used the Paypal Payments API to manage the payment side of new products, which now correctly produces an itemised transaction and allows the customer to checkout. But this does not produce an invoice.

How can I simultaneously produce an invoice (i.e which can be retrieved by the Invoicing API to show previous payments) and allow the customer to pay it? It seems like the Invoicing API works around the idea of sending an invoice to client by email, but this is unnecessary. I want them to pay it immediately (and already have the Payment API setup for this).

So what would a useful workflow be?: Use my Paypal Payment API to receive and authorise the payment, and on authorisation, use the Invoicing API to produce an invoice which reflects this and then updates the invoice status to paid? Or am I missing something easier here?

Answer (score 0):

The Invoicing API is not meant to be mixed or used with any other API. It is for generating invoices to be sent by email or in link form.

General ecommerce payment processing (without invoice links) is entirely separate, there is no crossover. You should ensure you are using the current v2/checkout/orders API to receive new payments, not older v1 APIs.

As far as displaying a list of previous purchases to your customers, you shouldn't reply on PayPal for this (except perhaps in the case of invoices since this is part of the point of offloading invoice management to PayPal). But for normal web purchases, PayPal is not a database -- it is a payment processing service. Keep track of all your own order information, and simply store PayPal transaction IDs when they complete for your own accounting records -- but the ID you reference with the customer should be your own unique order ID, which you can pass to PayPal in your `purchase_units[0].invoice_id` when you create an order for checkout approval.

Comment: Thank you. I don't really understand the issue with requesting transaction data and displaying it on your own website. Paypal is effectively a database of transactions. What is the point in the Transaction Search API if you cannot request some transactions which meet some criteria then do something with that info, like display it? Why bother storing it twice? I just wanted my app to interface Paypal and represent the data that already existed there.

Comment: I recommend using the transaction search API for exactly nothing, but it is there for certain use cases people insist on using it for. Don't expect any kind of reasonable performance compared to doing things the proper way (with your own database), which is how virtually every ecommerce software system worth its salt operates. Anyway, you've been reasonably warned against bothering with transaction search, but proceed as you will

Comment: I want to learn. Perhaps you can help me understand the "why" here? Are you advocating some general principle that I am unaware of, is it because the transaction search API is unreliable etc? Just telling someone not do something doesn't really help understand why not to. Why is "with your own database" the "proper" way? I thought it was perfectly reasonable and modern to request data like this.

Comment: Also, I'm not building an ecommerce system. I just want to show my clients some payments and help them make new ones.. but using Paypal.